# 2D Image Convolution - Central Difference on X-gradient

Tags: image-processing, graphics, computer-vision

I am trying to apply a kernel filter to compute the central difference x-gradient. A straight-forward way seems to be to apply the following kernel filter:

```
A = [
     0  0  0
    -1  0  1
     0  0  0
]
```

But since its values sum to zero, how do I normalize it? Is it legal to multiply it by a coefficient `0.5`? If so, could someone explain why?

Also, I vaguely remember that it might be desirable to apply something like

```
B = [
     0  1  0
     0  2  0
     0  1  0
]
```

before applying `A`, that is, `A * (B * f)` where `f` is the source image would be better than `A * f`, could someone help me understand what does `B` do and why it is better if it is?

Answer (score 0):

I think [Sobel and Scharr operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) and its explanation will clarify this subject to you. If this link will be deleted just google for "Sobel operator" - it is well known and described everywhere in the Internet. In two words: Sobel dx operator is combination of blur in oy-direction and simple central ox-difference. Blur performed for reducing artifacts associated with a pure central differences operator. Scharr operator is better optimized for rotational symmetry and "result from an optimization minimizing weighted mean squared angular error in Fourier domain" It's theory is a bit more complicated so you'd better visit wiki or read [Scharr paper](http://archiv.ub.uni-heidelberg.de/volltextserver/962/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: It is wiki link. Does someone know example of wiki link which became invalid? Anyway link name "Sobel operator" is a good clue to google it if wiki will suddenly disappear.

Comment: The comment is a canned option in the very low quality posts review queue, intended for link-only answers (not spam). Answers on SO should be self-standind and not only rely on linked material. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259

Answer (score 0):

To normalize an image kernel, divide by the sum of the absolute value of elements.

So for your first kernel, you have non-zero elements [-1,1], so |-1|+|1| = 1+1=2. So multiply by 1/2=0.5 to normalize. For edge-detection, you don't necessarily want to normalize. Normalizing image kernels is generally don't to avoid distorting the magnitude of pixels. Often you want this to emphasize edges when you're trying to detect them.

The kernel B is going two do things, first it will blur the image (all same signed non-zero elements), second it is only operating in the y-direction. The idea of applying this before your A-kernel is that it will do (sorta) a un-edge detection in the y-direction. Idea being to dampen the edges in the y-direction the detect edges in the x-direction.

Don't remember using this ever, but it makes some degree of sense.